# Vue props without using withDefaults loose reactivity

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have a component how used props and display it inside the template:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Variant } from '@/stores/@types/notification'

defineOptions({
  name: 'myComponent',
})

withDefaults(defineProps<{ variant?: Variant }>(), { variant: 'error' })
</script>

<template>
  <div :class="`component--${variant}`">
    <div>
      <div>{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
// ...
</style>
```

This works fine, but withDefaults is pretty ugly and i see this conference about vue, and now we can avoid using widthDefault (and the team try to remove it). See [the explains ir](https://youtu.be/CvWcKQYldUw?t=1181).

But when i apply this new setup, the props is undefined only inside the template the class is `component--undefined`.

```js
// Scenario 1
<script setup lang="ts">
const { variant = 'error' } = defineProps<{ variant?: Variant }>()

console.log(variant) 
// output 'error'
</script>
```

If i reassign the variable this works:

```js
// Scenario 2
<script setup lang="ts">
const { variant = 'error' } = defineProps<{ variant?: Variant }>()

const reassign = variant
</script>

<template>
  <div :class="`component--${reassign}`">
    <div>
      <div>{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

In that case the class is `component--error`. I think this is something about reactivity, because in the scenario 1, the console.log have `error`, but the template is undefined.

Based on from what I've seen, scenario 1 should work.

```js
"vue": "^3.3.7",
// devdepencies
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.4.1",
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
"typescript": "^5.0.2",
"vite": "^4.4.5",
```

Comment: The scenario 1 should work I test it in vuejs playground and it works

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Do you have a link? To see the version or other things. Maybe is related to that, i not understand why i'm not able to do it :(

Comment: The shared link is too long and I cannot paste it in a single comment, so I paste it here https://ctxt.io/2/AABQKwhuEw

Comment: Thanks! I try multiple things but not able to do it work on my project :(.
I thinks this 'new' feature is from vue-core so i don't know what can cause the issue.

Comment: This "new" feature has already been deprecated https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html . It's too magical even for script setup. You can use a third-party plugin thsat's suggested. The regular way to preserve reactivity is to use either withDefaults or a computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use Reactivity Transform.

1. You need to manually enable it in config: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#explicit-opt-in.
2. It is not recommended to use it and it will be removed in Vue 3.4. You can check out reasons and how to continue using it on the same page.

Comment: Oh indeed, sad :/
Thanks to found this!